# Posting health insurance details online

Tags: united-states, compensation, benefits

I need to select between two different health plans at my new employer and I'm not entirely clear on the difference between them. Is there any issue with posting the details online (on a Q&A site, Reddit, etc.), so that someone who understands this giant table can make sense of it for me? I wouldn't need to name the company, but it would presumably be obvious to anyone that worked there if they looked at the plans (not that they could trace it back to me anyways).

I think that discussing compensation details is a protected action in the US, is that right?

Comment: Have you tried asking the person who handed you the tables to explain it to you? I am sure you are not the first person to feel that way and you won't be the last, so surely there must be some way the others manage to deal with the problem.

Comment: @MaskedMan honestly, I trust people on e.g. /r/personalfinance more than my recruiter. He's also probably not interested in my decisions about benefits, since I've already been hired.

Comment: Have you tried speaking with your employer's HR department? When I was confused by some of the plan specifics at my new company, I spoke with an HR generalist who was able to answer my questions.

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard of it being against the law to discuss compensation packages.  Is this in writing from your employer?

From this (http://www.npr.org/2014/04/13/301989789/pay-secrecy-policies-at-work-often-illegal-and-misunderstood ) it does not appear to be the "law of the land" in the U.S.

If you signed a non-disclosure when you were hired, you may have given up your right to discuss certain topics.  A good NDA is written in a way that requires the disclosing party to label / document / summarize the information that is confidential.  Most employers don't have that clause, they just put in a vague statement that captures ever possible case.  Signing an NDA like that should be a last resort (like you can't get any other job).  It sets you up to be on the short-end-of-the-stick in a dispute.  They can merely claim that it was "obvious" that compensation was confidential, although I would disagree with this expectation.

Step 1.  Read any NDA you signed when you were hired
Step 2.  Discuss with HR informing them that you'd like to seek outside advice.  For example, you should have the right to get advice from a relative (e.g. parents) or a professional (e.g. tax attorney, tax accountant, or financial planner)

Rather than seek out an adversarial position, describe you legitimate concern and ask for permission.

Comment: It's illegal to _prohibit_ it - it's protected so that employees can organize properly.